# fewer iterations vs a fewer iterations

Tags: articles

> The process will terminate in **a** fewer iterations with method A.
>
> The process will terminate in fewer iterations with method A.

May I know which one is grammatical

Comment: Well, the second one. You can't ever say "a(n) iterations".

Comment: But you could say "a few iterations".

Answer (score 5):

The *indefinite article* can be used in the plural or in the singular form. **But** that article does have its own plural form: the *zero* form (there is nothing!):

Singular:

> An apple
>   A car

Plural:

> Apples
>   Cars

Since *fewer iterations* is a *plural* you should use the *plural* form of the article (nothing) and not the singular form (a/an).